# merging values in rows dependent on values in columns

Tags: python

let's say I have

```
col1  col2
Aa    1
As    2
Aa    1
Aj    4
af    2
As    3
```

**Program**

```
for rows in data_set:
      rows.strip()
      rows.split('\t')
      if rows[0] # this is where I'm lost
```

if values in Col1 equal each other merge their values, so that there exists one row with the Col2 values added. So for example here, the first row would be

```
Col1    Col2
Aa      2
As      5
```

and so forth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dict` to store Col2 values.

```
dict = {}
for rows in data_set:
      rows.strip()
      rows.split('\t')
      if rows[0] in dict:
         dict[rows[0]] += rows[1]
      else:
         dict[rows[0]]  = rows[1]
```

Then your dict would looks like this

```
{'Aa':2,'As':5}
```

Comment: this would be a good way of doing it, were I to only to have these 2 columns of data, now practically I have more columns than these 2. So I'm unsure the dictionary would work, as I understand the dictionary in python there exists only 2 values {key:value}. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Doug can you paste an example ?